How can I download and set a random wallpaper from Windows Spotlight on GNOME / Plasma?
How can I download and set a random wallpaper from Windows Spotlight on GNOME / Plasma?
If possible, I would like also:

For a notification to be displayed, showing information about the wallpaper;
To keep all downloaded wallpapers and to be able to access information about them even after a new wallpaper has been set.


if you want to get stunning backgrounds keep changing with a nice digital clock and also with changing quotes go to your app centre and download VARIETY application later thank me.

This will parse XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP in order to establish the running DE and download a random Windows Spotlight wallpaper using the Windows Spotlight's API in ~/.local/share/wallpapers (storing some relevant information such as the wallpaper's title and description in a JSON file in the same directory), adequately setting the wallpaper depending on the running DE and showing a notification containing the wallpaper's title and description.
Duplicate wallpapers and JSON files will be overwritten.
Dependencies (GNOME / Plasma; you could avoid installing qdbus-qt5 if you're planning on running this on GNOME):
sudo apt install curl jq libnotify-bin qdbus-qt5

You may want to change locale=en-US to get titles and descriptions in your language (country=US won't affect localization, but I believe it may affect the wallpapers sent in response by the API).
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set_wallpaper_gnome() {
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file://${1}"
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri-dark "file://${1}"
}

set_wallpaper_kde() {
    qdbus org.kde.plasmashell /PlasmaShell org.kde.PlasmaShell.evaluateScript "
        desktops().forEach((d) => {
            d.currentConfigGroup = [
                'Wallpaper',
                'org.kde.image',
                'General',
            ]
            d.writeConfig('Image', 'file://${1}')
            d.reloadConfig()
        })
    "
}

set -o pipefail

de=${XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP##*:}
{
    [ "${de}" = GNOME ] ||
    [ "${de}" = KDE ]
} || exit 1

country=US
locale=en-US

wallpapers_dir_path=~/.local/share/wallpapers
mkdir -p "${wallpapers_dir_path}" || exit 2

json=$(curl "https://fd.api.iris.microsoft.com/v4/api/selection"\
    -G\
    -A ''\
    --data-urlencode "bcnt=1"\
    --data-urlencode "country=${country}"\
    --data-urlencode "fmt=json"\
    --data-urlencode "locale=${locale}"\
    --data-urlencode "placement=88000820"\
    2>/dev/null |
        jq -c '
            .batchrsp.items[].item |
            fromjson |
            .ad |
            {
                description: .description,
                entityId: .entityId,
                landscapeImageAsset: .landscapeImage.asset,
                portraitImageAsset: .portraitImage.asset,
                title: .title,
            }
        '
)

[ ${?} -eq 0 ] || exit 3

IFS=$'\t' read -r description entity_id landscape_image_asset portrait_image_asset title\
    <<<"$(<<<"${json}" jq -r '[ .description, .entityId, .landscapeImageAsset, .portraitImageAsset, .title ] | @tsv')"

wallpaper_path="${wallpapers_dir_path}/${entity_id}.jpg"
json_path="${wallpaper_path%.*}.json"
json_link_path="${wallpapers_dir_path}/current.json"

curl -o "${wallpaper_path}" "${landscape_image_asset}" || exit 4
printf '%s\n' "${json}" >"${json_path}" || exit 5

{
    [ "${de}" = GNOME ] &&
        set_wallpaper_gnome "${wallpaper_path}" ||
        set_wallpaper_kde "${wallpaper_path}"
} || exit 6

ln -fs "${json_path}" "${json_link_path}" || exit 7

notify-send -a 'set-windows-spotlight-wallpaper' "${title}" "${description}"

All downloaded wallpapers along with their JSON files can later be found in ~/.local/share/wallpapers (on Plasma, this allows to easily set a previously downloaded wallpaper via System Settings); ~/.local/share/wallpapers/current.json will always be a symlink to the last set wallpaper's JSON file (e.g. jq -r '.title, .description' ~/.local/share/wallpapers/current.json will always print the last set wallpaper's title and description).
Tested on Ubuntu 24.04 / GNOME and OpenSuse Leap 15.6 / Plasma (I didn't get the chance to test it on Ubuntu / Plasma, but I don't see a reason why it wouldn't work on Ubuntu / Plasma).
Here's the thing running:


Use cases

#1 Randomly change the wallpaper every N minutes: you could create a cron job that runs the script every N minutes, but watch out for the number of wallpapers and JSON files downloaded in ~/.local/share/wallpapers; duplicate wallpapers and JSON files will be overwritten but I don't know how many unique wallpapers the API can return. You may want to comment out the notify-send line to disable the notifications;
#2 Randomly change the wallpaper on GNOME / Plasma startup: you could schedule the script to run on startup from GNOME / Plasma's settings;
#3 Randomly change the wallpaper at will: you could create a .desktop file that runs the script on double click.


TODO: skip downloading if the wallpaper returned by the API has been downloaded already. Incoming later
